# /var/www/html/ フォルダー内にPHPファイルを作成したい

Tags: linux

ドットインストールやudemyで学習している初心者です。

VirtualboxにMX Linux21をインストールし仮想環境を構築してみました。
ホストOSはWindows11です。Youtube動画を見ながらやってみました。

今回、仮想環境のLinux OS上でPHPを利用してみたいと思っています。
テキストエディタはVSCode、ブラウザはGoogle ChromeをLinuxOSにインストールしました。

PHPを利用出来るようにLinux OS内にLAMPの環境を構築しようと思っています。

こちらのサイトをgoogleの翻訳機能を利用して進めています。

https://mxlinux.org/wiki/networking/lamp-setup/

ApacheとPHPをインストールした後に「インストールをテストする」という項目があります。

> インストールをテストする PHPが正しく機能していることを確認するには、次の内容のindex.phpファイルを/ var / www /
> html /フォルダーに作成します。
>
> <？php  phpinfo（）; ？> 次に、ブラウザで「localhost
> /index.php」を指定します。すべてのPHP設定が表示されたテーブルを含むページが表示されます。

これが出来ればPHPのバージョン等の情報ページが表示されるはずです。そこで/ var / www / html /フォルダーに移動し右クリックでドキュメントを作成からPHPファイルを作成しようと思ったのですが「ドキュメントの作成」が選択できないようになっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

またデスクトップにindex.phpファイルを作成しドラッグアンドドロップしようとしたのですが何の反応もありません。
アクセス権にかかわる問題なのでしょうか？

ターミナルは開けるのでtouchコマンドでファイルを作成し、編集しようと思いまずファイルを作成したのですが

```
$ touch index.php
touch: 'index.php' に touch できません: 許可がありません
```

と作成の許可がないようです。

どのようにすれば /var/www/html/ フォルダーにPHPファイルを作成することが出来ますか？

恥ずかしながらLinuxや仮想環境に関してはほぼ初めて触るという状態です。初心者でもわかるように教えていただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

大抵のLinuxでは、/var/www/htmlはroot所有者になっているはずです。
その場合、一般ユーザーでは書き込み権限がありません。
su - でrootになってから作業してください。

```
ubuntu:~$ ls -ld /var/www/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 13 11:42 /var/www/

ubuntu:~$ ls -ld /var/www/html/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 13 11:53 /var/www/html/
```